# ruby searchkick failure : connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I want to implement a searchkick on my Rails app, thus I my added to my gem file :

```
gem 'elasticsearch'
gem 'searchkick'
```

, did a

```
bundle install
```

, and then

```
rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Pfile
```

It returns me the following error :

```
rake aborted!
 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)
 Tasks: TOP => searchkick:reindex
 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: run the trace and post it please rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Pfile  --trace

Comment: you probably misconfigured searchkick

Comment: Thanks guys , here is the trace :
     C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize'
     C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `open'
     C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `block in connect'
     C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'

I'm limited in terms of characters for the time being :/

Comment: are you running the elastic server, for example .. `sudo /usr/local/share/elasticsearch/bin/service/elasticsearch start`

Comment: how do I run it on a Windows env ? I'm sure I don't :)

Answer (score 0):

ran into this myself. try `elasticsearch -f -D es.config=/usr/local/opt/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml`